# ios in app purchases - validating receipt data

Tags: ios, app-store

i am implementing in app purchases into a iOS application. I am using the server model (so all the in app items are stored on my server). The purchase model works like this:

1. user buys a item in the application
2. application sends the receipt-data to my server (receipt-data is a digitally signed chunk of data)
3. the server then sends a verification to the apple server
4. if the verification is successful the server returns data about the transaction

I've been searching through the documentation but i cant answer this questions:

- can i validate that the receipt-data came from the apple store (checking the signiture or do i have to come up with a mechanism for that)?
- if a user buys a item that was removed from the store (due to an old cache) can i reject the purchase?

If anyone has any experience with this i would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can validate the receipt-data come from the apple store by following [Local validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html).
2. If user buy a removed item. It's mean product_id does not exist in Itune. Transaction will be fail. You should update Product Request, when user use IAP.